# Save Vue Component in localStorage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage

Im building an App that lets the user build an UI based on premade Vue Components. I save the ui in an tree like object containing the component structure together with some attributes. Now i want to save that state to the localStorage (and later to a Database), but i cant just do `JSON.stringify(component)` because it breaks when i assemble it back together (with `JSON.parse(component_string)`).

Example:

```
<script setup>

import TestComp from "../components/TestComp.vue";

const TestComp2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(TestComp))



</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <component :is="TestComp"></component>
        <component :is="TestComp2"></component>
    </div>

</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">

</style>
```

TestComp is just an component that does nothing and just displays a text. The first line runs fine, the second one prints a warning

```
[Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function. 
  at <TestComp> 
  at <Testing2View onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
```

Comment: JSON can't represent class instances, it can only save plain objects and arrays.

Comment: You'll need to save the data, then reconstruct it when you retrieve.

Comment: Yea but how do i save a vue component when i cant just stringify it?

Comment: You don't. You save the data you need, then recreate it when restoring.

Comment: You need global state to do this. Existing libs (vuex, pinia) have persistence plugins to save you from manual labour. The code above doesn't make sense because `TestComp` is a component, i.e. an object with `setup` function, etc, not component instance.

Comment: The code does make sense. I know that TestComp is a component and not an instance